# Nat Local subnet to another gateway centos7

Tags: centos, iptables, nat, route

hi i have a centos 7 with ocserv and iptables installed
i wanted to route all OCserv teraffic to ip tunnel (which established and reachable)

**my Server ip is 172.10.1.1**

**My OCSERV Users Subnet is : 192.168.8.0/24**

`the device i wanted to route 192.168.8.0/24 terrafic name is :l ipip and the ip of this device is 10.10.10.1`

i can connect to my server with ocserv client and i have 192.168.8.5 ip address on my client device but i cant access to internet

Comment: how is `172.10.1.1` related to `10.10.10.1` and how is that related to the `192.168.8.0/24` subnet - i.e. some sort of network diagram may help - also, you used the made up word `terrafic` twice. Is that supposed to be `traffic`?

Comment: thanks, yes i meant traffic , sorry for my bad english

Comment: i wanted to re route my ourgoing ocserv traffic to 10.10.10.1 instead of Default Gateway